# Customizing a table view to achieve a 'gallery' look

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I'm trying to create a gallery of images using a UITableView. The application I'm trying to build is similar to the iBook app.

[image]

Are there any blogs/resources out there that talk about achieving the 'gallery' look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AQGridview](https://github.com/pjay/AQGridView#readme) provides the functionailty.